# Why isn't $\frac{d}{dx} \sin (2x) = \cos (2x)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

$g=\sin$, $g'=\cos$

If $g(x)=\sin(x)$, then $g'(x)=\cos(x)$.

Then $g(y)=\sin(y)$ and $g'(y)=\cos(y)$.

Let $y=2x$.

Then $g(y)=\sin(2x)$ and $g'(y)=\cos(2x)$, but if $h(x)=\sin(2x)$, then $h'(x)=2\cos(2x)$,
so $h(x)=g(y)$, but $h'(x)$ is not equal to $g'(y)$ if, say, $x = \pi$.

This doesn't make sense to me, isn't to say $h(x)=g(y)$ to say that $h(x)$ and $g(y)$ are the same?  and so wouldn't it follow that $h'(x)=g'(y)$?

Is my problem that I am looking at individual values, $h(x)$ and $g(y)$, instead of the functions $h$ and $g$ themselves?

Edit: Once I thought to think of derivative as slope and realized that the slope of the line tangent to the graph of $h(x)$ at $x=a$ is not necessarily the same as the slope of the line tangent to the graph of $g(x)$ at $x=a$, I understood (satisfactorily) why $g'(x)$ isn't the same as $h'(x)$.

Comment: You are using primes to denote two different things, which we can loosely describe as "derivatives with respect to x" and "derivatives with respect to y"

Comment: @Mariano: The primes mean the same thing in both cases: "The derivative of the univariate function that is decorated with the prime".

Comment: they cannot mean that, for otherwise, for example, the equalities $g(y)=\sin(2x)$ and $g'(y)=\cos(2x)$ are simply incompatible.

Comment: What's the problem? $g' = \cos$, so $g'(y) = \cos y = \cos(2x)$

Comment: Hurkyl is correct about the meaning of "prime". However, there is implicit equivocation involved in the OP's conclusion. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Try using chain rule:
$$
(\sin(\varphi(t)))'_{t}=\varphi'(t) \cos(\varphi(t))
$$
Setting $\varphi(t)=2t$ you get $(\sin(\varphi(t)))'_{t}=2 \cos2t$

Answer (score 3):

If you compare the graph of $y=\sin(x)$ to that of $y=\sin(2x)$, the latter is compressed toward the $y$ axis by a factor of $1/2$ compared to the former. This contraction definitely will double slopes, at least if such slopes aren't $0$.

But $\cos(2x)$ never reaches above $1$ or below $-1$, so some points on $y=\sin(2x)$ will have slopes unreachable by $\cos(2x)$.

Comment: Please \cos x gives you $\cos x$, whereas cos x gives you $cos x$.  Both spacing and italicization are affected.

Comment: A minor point: if the original slope is $0$, then so is the doubled slope, so it still works even then.

Comment: Cameron: Yes, twice zero is zero. But it's not zero!. Because zero! means $0!$ which is 1.

Comment: Michael: Thanks for the edit!. I do know some LaTex but some of the fine points still elude me. I guess writing $cosx$ gives something not as good as $\cos x$. Hmm: just now I included the flanking dollar signs and even the comment was the LaTex version. Probably should have written \frac{1}{2} also.

Answer (score 2):

Given a function $f$ in one variable--say $t$, for example--we use $f'(t)$ to denote $\frac{d}{dt}\bigl[f(t)\bigr],$ so we're taking the derivative with respect to the *given* variable.

Now, let me translate the problematic point into the *other* notation, so that I can clarify the problem:

> "This doesn't make sense to me, isn't to say $h(x)=g(y)$ to say that $h(x)$ and $g(y)$ are the same? and so wouldn't it follow that $\frac{d}{dx}\bigl[h(x)\bigr]=\frac{d}{dy}\bigl[g(y)\bigr]$?"

The answer to the first question is yes. To the second, however, the answer is no. Now, if we took the derivative on both sides *with respect to the same variable*, then the latter answer would also be yes. However, to do this correctly, we'll probably need to use the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

Taking $\,f(x):=\sin 2x\,$ , we get:

$$\sin 2x-\sin 2x_0=2(\sin x\cos x-\sin x_0\cos x_0)=$$

$$=2(\sin x\cos x-\sin x\cos x_0+\sin x\cos x_0-\sin x_0\cos x_0)$$

Thus, by the definition of derivative, using the above, using the formulae for the double angle ($\,\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x\,\,,\,\,\cos 2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x\,$) and taking into account

that $\,(\sin x)'=\cos x\,\,,\,\,(\cos x)'=-\sin x\,$ , we get:

$$f'(x_0):=\lim_{x\to\ x_0}\frac{\sin 2x-\sin 2x_0}{x-x_0}=2\lim_{x\to x_0}\,\left[\sin x\frac{\cos x-\cos x_0}{x-x_0}+\cos x_0\frac{\sin x-\sin x_0}{x-x_0}\right]=$$

$$=2\left[\sin x_0(-\sin x_0)+\cos x_0(\cos x_0)\right]=2(\cos^2x_0-\sin^2x_0)=2\cos 2x_0$$

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another perspective: It is true that $\sin'(x) = \cos(x)$.  It therefore follows that $\sin'(2x) = \cos(2x)$.  However, the derivative of $\sin(2x)$ is not $\sin'(2x)$.  The function $\sin(2x)$ is the composite of $x\mapsto 2x$ and $x\mapsto\sin(x)$, and the chain rule tells you how both parts contribute to the derivative of the total:  $$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(2x) = \left(\frac{d}{dx}(2x)\right)\sin'(2x) = 2\sin'(2x) = 2\cos(2x).$$

Answer (score 0):

It is true that if if $h = g$, then $h' = g'$.

Equality of functions is given pointwise: $h=g$ is true if and only if $h(a) = g(a)$ for every real number $a$.

However, $h=g$ is not true: $h(a) = \sin(2a)$ but $g(a) = \sin a$, and these are usually different.

Now, $h(x) = g(y)$ is indeed true: both sides express the same functional dependence on $x$, or equivalently of $y$. Correspondingly, their differentials are the same:

$$ d(h(x)) = d(g(y)) $$
$$ h'(x) \,dx = g'(y) \,dy $$
$$ 2 \cos 2x\,dx = \cos y \,dy $$

Since $y = 2x$, we also have $dy = 2 dx$, and so everything works out.

Of course, if you're not comfortable with differentials, all of the above remains the same if you pick a specific variable to differentiate both sides with respect to. i.e. if $x$ and $y$ are both functions of $t$, then we have

$$ \frac{d}{dt} h(x) = \frac{d}{dt} g(y) $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = 2 \frac{dx}{dt} $$

and we can do a similar calculation.